# How to change decimal separator in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

my excel 2013 uses a comma (",") to separate decimals in a number. How can I format it that it uses a dot (".") to separate the decimals?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

First of all, excel may be using the system default decimal separator. You can change this one in the region and language settings, which is found in the control panel.

The second option is to tell excel not to use the system-wide value and specify them yourself.  You find the relevant setting for this under [file] [options][advanced]

[image: Excel 2013 file]

[image: excel 2013 options]

[image]

---

And here are the screenshots for doing it via region and language. Note that this may affect more programs than just excel. This might be desirable to get a consistent setup, or it may disturb some other fragile setup.

[image: Windows 7 start control panel]

[image: Windows 7 control panel Region and language]

[image: Windows 7 Region and language settings]

**IGNORE THE YELLOW IN THE LAST SCREENSHOT**
I do not have excel 2013 at home (I use openoffice). These were screenshots taken a few weeks ago when I needed to explain something similar involving the list separator. For your question use the *digit grouping* symbol.