# Excel office 365 (online version) - changing decimal separator

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I have a problem when I sum decimal numbers in the online excel (office 365). I discovered that it's because of the decimal separator.

The default separator is comma `,` but I want it to be dot instead.

I know how to change it locally, like here: [How to change decimal separator in excel](https://superuser.com/questions/859510/how-to-change-decimal-separator-in-excel), but I don't know how to do that in the online version of excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't SUM something, it probably means the data are not formatted as a number. Otherwise, your browser should be using your system settings to display the number, which means Excel (online or otherwise) doesn't actually have the comma in the number, it just displays it that way:

[image]

You can see that it's displayed with commas, but in the formula bar, there are no commas.

If you see commas in the formula bar, you are trying to sum text.

You can use this formula:

```
=NUMBERVALUE()
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: I'm talking about decimals like (e.g. `0.52`), Also the cell format is number not string.
Anyways, this `NUMBERVALUE` solve my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Excel Online supports numbers input in different formats, including using “.” or “,” as a decimal separator, but the way you control that input is little weird in that and it’s inherited from your Microsoft Account Profile, and is based on the region you've listed there.

To change the region from Microsoft Account, Go to [Your Profile](https://account.microsoft.com/profile/), Click on "Region" and change it to your specific region. Now, open a spreadsheet in online excel, and try entering a number. This should do the job as it has done mine  :)

Comment: I'm using business version, thus I'm not able to change these settings.